# Rails - syntax for combining statements in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am struggling on how to write the following controller action as one line. I am having a hard time figuring out how to research the answer or even the correct terminology as I am new to Rails and Ruby.  How do I write the following as one line?

```
Response.create(params[:response].values)
Response.create(:responseset_id => @responseset.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response.create(params[:response].merge({:responseset_id => @responseset.id})`

answer following feedback:

```
params[:response].each do |k,v|
  Response.create({:question_id => k, :response_set_id => @responseset.id}.merge(v))
end
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I need to keep the `.values` or else my code will break.  How would I add in `.values` to the above statement? I tried some different variations with no success.

Comment: that would give you an array of values though with no data for what their key should be. what is params[:response]? are you trying to create a single Response, one for each params[:response] or something else?

Comment: for example: params[:response] = {"2" => {"user_answer" => "3"}, "3" => {"user_answer" => "4"}... and so on}. I couldn't use the submitted params directly, so I had to take the params[:response] and then convert the hash into an array: [{"user_answer" => "3", "question_id" => "2"}, {"user_answer" => "4", "question_id" => "3"}, and so on]. It is coming from my view: `<%= fields_for "response[#{q.id}]" do |f| %>`